# Unable to route to the same component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm making a simple file navigation UI using React. My route is set like the following:

```
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/app/file/' component={Files}/>
      <Route path='/app/file/:id' component={FilesNav}/>
    </Switch>
```

In both `Files` and `FilesNav` components, I have the following piece of code:

`` <Link to = {`/app/file/${file_id}`}></Link> ``

Now, when I hit this `Link to` path from the `Files` component, it successfully renders the `FilesNav` component for me. However, since it's a file system and there will be nested folders, I also need to hit the `/app/file/:id` path from the `FilesNav` component itself, and this is where it's not working. It updates the query param with the correct id, but it doesn't render the `FilesNav` component for me again, I'm assuming this is because I'm trying to render a component that I'm already inside of? Can someone please give me an idea how to fix this?

For more context, here's the code for `FilesNav`:

```
class FilesNav extends Component{


    componentDidMount(){
        const { id } = this.props.match.params
        this.props.showContents(id)
    }

    upload = value => {
        const { id } = this.props.match.params;
        const file = value.file
        this.props.uploadFile(file, id)
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h3>Files</h3>
                <div>
                <List
                    bordered
                    dataSource={this.props.folderContents}
                    renderItem={item => (<List.Item><Link to = {`/app/file/${item.id}`} key = {item.id}>{item.name}</Link></List.Item>)}
                />
                </div>
                <span>
                    <Upload className='upload-button' customRequest={this.upload} showUploadList={false}>
                    <Button><FontAwesomeIcon icon='upload' />Upload</Button>
                    </Upload>
                </span>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps({...}){
    return{
        ...  
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps ,{ uploadFile, showContents })(FilesNav);
```

Edit: Added code for FilesNav

Comment: Where and how is the `file_id` variable declared?

Comment: What is the desired behavior? If you are already on that route, what should happen if you click a link to that same route?

Comment: @trixn, The desired behavior is as follows: Let's say I'm on the `FilesNav` component (which shows files+folders for a particular directory), I click on the link (that has the id for another folder), I'm expecting it to render the same `FilesNav` component again, but it should show different data now, since the `id` is different. Does that make sense?

Comment: @nschwan94, on the `Files` component, it's coming from an action_creator and on the `FilesNav` component, it comes from `this.props.match.params`, in other words from the request parameter.

Comment: @BobSilas Yes that makes sense. How are you using the `id` inside your `FilesNav` component? If you use it inside the `render()` method and the `id` changes the component should automatically re-render with the new id. Please show us the code of `FilesNav`.

Comment: @trixn, added code on the original question.

Comment: Well the `render()` function of `FilesNav` doesn't use the id in any way. It will not make a visual difference which route you are currently on. The only point where it seems to be used is in the upload handler. What makes you think that `FilesNav` does not re-render? It probably does but you see no difference in markup. Try render `this.props.match.params.id` and you will probably see, that it changes with the url.

Comment: if `this.props.showContents(id)` is what you need to call to show the right content, put it in a `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle definition. otherwise, @trixn is right, there doesn't appear to be a UI change in `FilesNav` render that is based on query param.

Comment: @trixn, The code that you see inside `componentDidMount` triggers the expected behavior. I understand what you're suggesting, that I'm not causing any re-render with the new id inside the render method. Could you give me an idea how to do that in this case? Basically, upon clicking the `Link to` path, I want to call the `this.props.showContents(id)` method again, so that it gives me the new list of files and folders for the new id.

Comment: @BobSilas In this case do what @nschwan94 suggested and implement `componentDidUpate()` where you check if the `id` changed and call `showContents()` again with the new id. `componentDidMount()` will only be called once during mounting. Changing the id in the route does not lead to a re-mounting. Only the props will be updated in that case if the component is already mounted.

Comment: @nschwan94, I tried doing what you said. While it does let me navigate to the expected folder now, it falls in an infinite loop. I have a couple of console logs from the action creator method and they keep logging the exact same thing in a loop until I manually stop the server.

Comment: One note: This may not be the best solution depending on what happens in `showContents`. It strongly seems like a design smell that you need to do that at all. But this can only be evaluated by knowing more of the code.

Comment: In case it helps anyone, I fixed this issue by getting rid of `Link to` on `FilesNav` and simply using the anchor tag and calling `this.props.showContents` in an onClick function. That fixed it.